# php array count max value

Tags: php

If I have:
$mainarray = some array of things with some repeated values

```
$array_counted = array_count_values ($mainarray);
```

How can I find the maximum value in $array_counted?

(This would be the element that appeared most often in $mainarray I think.  Its mostly a syntax issue as I am pretty sure I could loop it, but not sure of the syntax to use)

Answer (score 1):

You can find first max value as

```
$main_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6);
$max_val = max($main_array);
```

for find all of max vals 
in php < 5.3

```
  function findmax($val)
{
    global $max_val;
    return $val == $max_val;
}
$max_values_array = array_filter($main_array,'findmax');
```

in php >= 5.3

```
 $max_values_array = array_filter($main_array,function($val) use  ($max_val)  {  return $val == $max_val; }); 

echo count($max_values_array);
```

var_dump($max_values_array);

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array and take the first, respectively last item out of it, if you don't want to loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you associate the count with the values with that:

```
$array_counted = array_count_values ($mainarray);
```

You only need to sort it afterwards, and return the first key (which is the most occured element):

```
arsort($array_counted);
print key($array_counted);  // returns first key
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, the guy whos answer I used has deleted his comment so here is how I did it:

I used arsort($array_counted) to sort the array, while keeping index.  rsort alone does not work as the result of array_count_values is an associative array.  Thank you all.